# What is a good game engine for a pixelated 2D game?

Tags: c#

I'm currently learning C# with Visual Studio Express 2012, and I have a few game ideas for the future. I just have trouble figuring out how to start (I'm 15) and I was wondering what would be a nice game engine for that sort of game.

Comment: If you can find visual studio 2010 - XNA, otherwise Unity. Also if you don't have any programming experience, there is GameMaker

Comment: This is a subjective question, and the answer will depend purely on people's opinion, which makes the question unsuitable for SO.

Comment: @MikeJohnson - You will soon come to realise that these questions get asked **A LOT** on SO, and it starts to dilute the page of valid questions with questions that can be easily found through google, there isn't a right answer to the question and the answer everyone would give is based off what they have already used themselves or have heard about with high esteem.

Comment: Meh, I'd rather give the kid an answer and help him start on his way, rather than handing him his hat and sending him walking lol

Answer (score 2):

XNA would be perfect for this, although if you want to use .NET 4.5 you will have to go through some minor annoyances to get it running in visual studio 2012 and .net 4.5

Another (better in my opinion) alternative is SharpDX. SharpDX is primarily a very well built managed DirectX API, built directly from the header files of the native DirectX. SharpDX includes a collection of additional assemblies called "Toolkit.{namespace name here}" that provide exactly what XNA provided, but in most cases, much more ideal. Should be noted that the toolkit class designs were based off the structuring of the XNA framework. SharpDX will require you to have an understanding of DirectX to take full advantage of it's capabilities, but you won't find this much capability in ANY other managed DirectX wrapper. Period (yes that's counting SlimDX as well).

Monogame (Mono's version of XNA is another solution, that for the moment, supports even mobile and Windows 8). Monogame has a nice bonus to it: It has nice support for cross-platform development. However, that bonus is also it's downside. Due to it's internal structuring, it's performance is poor compared to other options.

As mentioned in a comment, Unity is another popular option. You write in c# and support for javascript as well. Personally, I see a lot of future potential for Unity.

Just a note about XNA if you go that route: XNA is dead. Microsoft will not be supporting it after next year I believe they said. To be honest, windows 8 game development in c# has been somewhat left out in the cold at the moment (with the exception of Mono's version of XNA). Be warned about Mono though, although it works well, functionally speaking, it's performance is horrid (despite what mono-lovers will say). If you don't believe me, check the source code of it for yourself.

Another emerging popular choice is HTML5 and javascript. Seriously. You can do some absolutely astonishing  javascript graphics with libs like three.js on an html5 canvas. Much more than I would have expected for a scripting language.

And on a final note, the old tried and true c++ and DirectX/OpenGL. C++ is by far the most powerful of the programming languages and for this reason it is the most heavily used in game development. Unfortunately, it is also the most difficult to become efficient in and the concepts involved in creating a fully-functional game can take years to master even. Correction, it WILL take years. However, it's the most rewarding choice in the end.

Answer (score 1):

XNA and Unity are definitely the way to go, for new programmers to learn about game programming.

Also pay attention to the basic algorithms and data structures you learn in school. Another common method of learning game programming, back in my day, was to download, edit and run a MUD.

Comment: I had a feeling some other mud player out there would up-vote this =P

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.waveengine.net/

It's awesome that you are into game dev already!